# Functions with a best linear approximation

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, reference-request

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.
Fix a point $x_0$ throughout.

Assume that all directional derivatives of $f$ exist and they are linear with respect to the direction, meaning $v \to D_{v}$ is  a linear map where $D_v$ is the derivative IN the direction $v$.
Geometrically we get a plane that is the 'best' linear approximation of $f$  at $x_0$.

Even then $f$ may not be differentiable at $x_0$ even if it is continuous.
example $f(x, y) = \frac{x^3y}{x^4 + y^2}$ and defined $0$ at $0$ and take $x_0 = 0$.

So, such functions which have a 'best linear approximation' are a larger class than differentiable functions. One can check that they are closed under addition and multiplication. Is this class interesting? Is this notion of weaker derivative studied in the literature, because the examples for such functions that I could find (as above are not pathological also).

Also the best linear appoximation can be made rigorous as if there is a linear $D_2$ such that $|f(x_0+h) - f(x_0) - D(v)h| < |f(x_0+h) - f(x_0) - D_2(v)h|$ for all $h$ sufficiently small then $D_2 = D$(the linear function returning the directional derivatives).

I understand this quesition is a bit vague but any comments or insights are also most welcome.

Comment: Possibly something relevant to your question can be found in (or within the references of) [*The genesis of separate versus joint continuity*](http://zpiotrowski.people.ysu.edu/papers/genesisseperatevsjoint.pdf) (1996) and [*Separate versus joint continuity — an update*](http://www.math.bas.bg/smb/2000_PK/tom_2000/pdf/093-106.pdf) (2000), both by Zbigniew Piotrowski. See also some more recent papers **(continued)**

Comment: by [Krzysztof Chris Ciesielski](https://math.wvu.edu/~kciesiel/publications.html), such as [*Sets of discontinuities of linearly continuous functions*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/real-analysis-exchange/volume-38/issue-2/Sets-of-Discontinuities-of-Linearly-Continuous-Functions/rae/1403894898.full) (2013) and [*A continuous tale*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/real-analysis-exchange/volume-41/issue-1/A-Continuous-Tale/rae/1490752816.full) (2016). And maybe also [*A remark on functions continuous on all lines*](https://eudml.org/doc/294315) by Luděk Zajíček (2019).